# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hadoop'

Tags: python, hadoop, environment-variables, mlflow

I am currently trying to set up a Mlflow tracking server with a HDFS artifact store. However when I try to log a model to the HDFS in Jupyter Notebook, I receive this error:

```
File /usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:1845, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1843     if errno_num != 0:
   1844         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1845     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1846 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hadoop'
```

I have hadoop installed and configured and I believe my environment variables are set up correctly as well. They are shown here:

```
export PATH="/home/auto/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/auto/hadoop-3.3.4

export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Edit: Environment Variables used by Jupyter:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/auto-virtual-machine:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1684,unix/auto-virtual-machine:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1684
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=gnome-keyring
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE=session
PWD=/home/auto/test
LOGNAME=auto
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
JPY_SESSION_NAME=MLflow Live Demo.ipynb
SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID=1684
_=/usr/bin/env
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.6CXZW1
HOME=/home/auto
USERNAME=auto
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
VTE_VERSION=6800
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/534f59fb_c9a6_456a_a38d_0f37b80cf726
CLICOLOR=1
GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY=:1
JPY_PARENT_PID=15426
KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=True
KMP_INIT_AT_FORK=FALSE
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-color
USER=auto
GIT_PAGER=cat
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.188
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=0
PAGER=cat
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=abe24557a2edb707c37a5e24639b3f1d
MPLBACKEND=module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=abe24557a2edb707c37a5e24639b3f1d
```

Comment: Can you show the environment variables being used by jupyter? e.g. create a cell with `!env` and run it.

Comment: @NickODell I have added photos of the jupyter enviornment variables.

Comment: Can you copy and paste those into the question rather than as an image?

Comment: @NickODell Yes I just did. My apologies, I'm new to posting on here. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Looking at the `PATH` variable from Jupyter, it looks like it is missing the `$PATH` element you add in your `.bashrc`. That could cause it to not find your hadoop executable. Do you know how this Jupyter notebook is running?

Comment: @NickODell I noticed that as well and realized it's because I had opened jupyter notebook by clicking on the .ipynb file instead of using the terminal to run jupyter notebook. Silly mistake. All is working fine now. Thanks for helping me with that!

Comment: "clicking" still launches a shell process, therefore should still evaluate your shell profile. Perhaps you can use /etc/profile instead